# Adding a dictionary into a dictionary in a for loop with update()

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to add a temporary dictionary that gets generated every iteration in a for loop into a final dictionary. The aim of this final dictionary is to summurize every temporary dictionary that was generated in the loop. The keys of the temporary dictionary are numbers generated randomly, and the values are lists of random numbers too.
While searching on forums to find how to do this, I often came across the update() function, meant to work as follows : final_dictionary.udpate(temporary_dictionary).
However, I'm encountering a problem with this function. Here's my code :

```
import random
final_dictionary = {}
for i in range(30):
     rd_key = random.randint(1, 10)
     rd_value = [random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(0, 10)]
     temp_dictionary = {rd_key: rd_value}
     final_dictionary.update(temp_dictionary)
```

What I want from this loop is for the final dictionary to contain 30 items corresponding to the 30 temporary dictionaries that were generated every iteration in the loop.

However, every time I run the program I obtain a final dictionary that contains only 9 items, corresponding to some, but not all, temporary dictionaries that were generated in the loop.
Does anyone have any idea as to why this happens?
(I'm working on Python 3.7.9)

Comment: How many keys do you expect/want in the *final_dictionary* ?

Comment: 30 keys would be great

Comment: In which case, forget about *rd_key* and use *i* in its place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary keys are *unique*. `rd_key = random.randint(1, 10)` can produce 9 unique keys: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. Thus, the maximum size of `final_dictionary` is 9 elements.

Comment: Even if I change the 'rd_key = random.randint(1, 10)' to 'rd_key = random.randint(1, 40)', I only get 20 items in the final dictionary.

Comment: Try running `len({random.randint(1, 40) for _ in range(30)})` multiple times - this will compute the length of your dictionary with randomly generated keys. It's not uncommon to get 20 elements. In fact, the mean number of items seems to be around `21.24`.

Comment: Your outer loop specifies 30 iterations. In your modified code you make 30 pseudo random selections from the range 1->40. You are likely to get duplication. Try running it several times. You are likely to get different results each time you run it

Comment: It indeed returns values between 18 and 23 for the majority